# Can't move files,error- file used by another process with c#, windows 10 & VS 2015

Tags: c#, file, windows-10-desktop

I know this is common question with easy answer but i cannot move files from one folder to another on win10 machine with VS 2015 as its throws exception: cannot access file(some file) its used by another process. I executed same code on win7 machine and it worked correctly.

I checked file locked or not before move process.Is there any issue with windows 10 machine file to access? There is no problem while performing copy operation.

For move i have used File.Move("Source",Destination").
Even i cannot read file with FileStream with read or write permission,gives same error.

Is there anything i am missing to perform on files so that given exception shouldn't come?

Please give some pointers.I have spent lot of time to google it but no luck.
Thanks in advance.